# How do I check if a specific return type is accepted by the client?

Tags: php, http, http-headers

I'm building an API, and I'd like to let my clients specify the content formats they accept in my responses (xml, json, etc).

I'd also like to do it using the `Accept` section of the request.

Somewhere in my code, I call the following line:

```
$request->getAcceptableContentTypes();
```

which returns

```
array (size=5)
  0 => string 'text/html' (length=9)
  1 => string 'application/xhtml+xml' (length=21)
  2 => string 'image/webp' (length=10)
  3 => string 'application/xml' (length=15)
  4 => string '*/*' (length=3)
```

This specific request accepts both xml and json returns... but I'm not sure how to verify that. A XML response is allowed (both by `*/*`, `application/xhtml+xml` and `application/xml`), but its primary MIME type would be `text/xml`, which is not explicitly written above. Same thing applies to `application/json`, which is allowed by `*/*`, but isn't explictly written.

Should I map all the possible mimetypes to its equivalents, should I enforce a specific and explict mimetype definition on my client or is there a more elegant way to do that?

**EDIT:** For clarification: I get `Accepts: application/xhtml+xml`. I'm only prepared to answer with `Content-Type: text/xml`. Should I throw an exception? Or should I explode the second part (xhtml+xml) and return `text/xml` anyway, due to the similarity of what's accepted and what I can answer? If so, how do I know they're "similar"? Will I need a lookup table? Can I disregard the first part (`application`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This process is called **content negotiation**.

The representation (html, json or xml) returned by a API web service is determined by the URL or by the Accept HTTP header.

Let's start to view at this from client-side:

```
GET http://api.company.com/products/10 HTTP/1.1
Host: http://api.company.com
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
```

The server responds with

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: ...
Connection: Close

{"Id":1,"ProductName":"Helicopter","Category":"Aircraft","Price":5000}
```

---

Question: How do i check, if a specific return type is accepted by the client?"

Answer: by evaluating the accept header send by the client.

In the GET-request the client defines multiple accept headers (in order) (with preference q). The Accept-Header lists the mime-types that the client is willing to accept.

The tasks of the server would be to look at the available representations it has and serve the one with the highest preference to the client.
You have to evaluate the "Accept"-headers and the "q"-weight and send an appropriate representation to the client, indicating the type in the Content-Type - header.

The "q" argument in the Accept header is float between 0 and 1. It's a weight, indicating the preference for that media type. A higher number inidicates a higher preference.
The offical term is "relative quality factor".

The RFC describes several examples of how the preference should be understand.
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

It's not easy. Some of these things are "overlapping".
Keep it easy. Focus on "text/html", "application/json", "application/xml".

---

How can one implement that on server side? 
It is a good practice to have a Negotiation class.

Let's say: the client requests a valid resource, but with unknown Accept header.

```
GET http://api.company.com/products/10 HTTP/1.1
Host: http://api.company.com
Accept: application/karamba
```

- The request comes to the server.
- The resource /product/10 is found - it's valid. The server has data.
- Now "application/karamba" arrives, but there is not content-formatter for that.
- The server can't deliver the format the client wants it's data in.
- The server has to send an error 406 (Not Acceptable) as Response.

---

The workflow is roughly like this:

1. Request Object with a method preferedResponseType() to evaluate the Accept Header

   - or like you have it already $request->getAcceptableContentTypes()
   - good lib: http://williamdurand.fr/Negotiation/
2. instantiate an Response object, based on that type. 
   you might do that by mapping part of the string from the accept header to a class.

   - JsonResponse
   - XmlResponse
   - HtmlResponse
3. if, there isn't a response object for this type (it's unknown)

   - send an ErrorResponse. EXIT
4. fetch data from db
5. insert db results into response object, maybe JsonResponse()
6. JsonResponse()->flush() send it...

The essential part is the mapping from Accept Header to a Class which can answer that request.

Finally, you have to make a decision, if you really want to support many Response types.

---

Ok, so much theory. Let's take a look at a live API: GitHub.

- Request to https://api.github.com/users/caspyin
- browser based GET request to the API endpoint
- with Accept Header `text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8`
- Response is JSON send with `Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8`
- Wait. What? Why?
- Github responses are JSON, because they decided to keep it simple.
- They expose their accepted mime-types here: https://developer.github.com/v3/media/#request-specific-version

---

Update (2014-09-29)
Check out this new library: **https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Accept**

Especially: https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Accept/blob/master/tests/unit/src/MediaTest.php

Comment: This is a great answer, but it doesn't quite answer my question. @Issam Zoli already answered (kind of), but there is still one thing I don't quite understand: if the client requests a response as `application/xml`, should I respond with `text/xml` (if this is the only available response format in my server)? Or should I respond with a HTTP 406?

Comment: Your server defines it! The client implements it according to your API description! Updated my answer with a link to the new Aura.Accept library. It's a simple parser, taking the q value into account, like i described in my answer. https://github.com/pmjones/Aura.Accept/blob/master/src/AbstractNegotiator.php#L147

Answer (score 1):

You need to do pattern matching not equality checking:

- `application/xml+json` != `application/json`
- `application/xml+json` != `application/xml`

But `application/json` matches `application/xml+json`

One thing you could do is flatten accept headers with `+` and do consecutive matching if only there is no `*/*` till you find an acceptable format else return `406 Not Acceptable`.

```
<?php

$accept = [
    'text/html',
    'application/json+xml',
    'image/webp',
    'application/xml',
    '*/*'
];

function flattenAccept($accept) {
    $newAccpet = [];
    foreach ($accept as $mimeType) {
        if (strpos($mimeType, '+') !== false) { // Contains +
            $arr = explode('/', $mimeType);
            $type = $arr[0];
            $medias = explode('+', $arr[1]);
            foreach ($medias as $media) {
                array_push($newAccpet, $type."/".$media); // Flatten
            }
        } else {
            array_push($newAccpet, $mimeType);
        }
    }
    return array_unique($newAccpet);
}


function matching($mimeType, $accept) {
    if (in_array("*/*", $accept)) return true;
    return in_array($mimeType, $accept);
}

$newAccept = flattenAccept($accept);
var_dump($newAccept);
var_dump(matching("application/json", $newAccept));
```

Result

```
array(5) {
  [0] =>
  string(9) "text/html"
  [1] =>
  string(16) "application/json"
  [2] =>
  string(15) "application/xml"
  [3] =>
  string(10) "image/webp"
  [5] =>
  string(3) "*/*"
}
bool(true)
```

Comment: This is a great answer, the only one that answers my original question. There is still one issue: if the client requests a response as `application/xml`, should I respond with `text/xml` (if this is the only available response format in my server)? Or should I respond with a HTTP 406 (Not acceptable)?

Comment: My answer is not perfect though, there many synonyms mime types like `application/xml` and `text/xml` also some variants like `image/jpeg` and `image/jpg` those cases need special processing there isn't a general rule. For xml which interests you, according to the RFC http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3023.txt it's pretty much interchangeable so I think you just return response

Comment: Out of curiosity, what makes you believe that `application/json` matches `application/xml+json`? I didn't see this mentioned in any RFC that describes `Accept` header parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Most APIs which allow multiple MIME type responses force the client to specify the response format. These are usually done in one of 2 ways: either as a query parameter ('http://exampleAPI.com/getAllUsers?json') or as a request header ('Accept: application/json').

Requiring this from the client will give you explicit values for the accepted MIME types and you can decide if you'd like to respond with an error or apply a default setting when it's missing or incorrect.

This solution won't give your client an overhead either, as in a generic client-side implementation, you would create a wrapper class to automate authentication and maybe to organise your requests and post-process your responses in certain cases.

Comment: I don't think this answers my question. If my user specifies `Accept: application/xml+json`, should I throw an exception, telling him `application/xml+json` is not allowed, only `application/xml` and `application/json`? It makes no sense, as the application/xml+json includes application/json and application/xml.

Comment: APIs are usually strict by definition, so you create the options for the client and not the other way around. If you require the clients to specify an `Accept` header, you are in full control what happens when they specify `application/xml+json` - but it's up to you. You can even throw an error if this is what you decide to do or even default to whichever you prefer if the `Accept` header is not specified correctly.
If I was building the API, I'd choose to deal with a set selection of `Accept` headers forcing the client to use ONLY the available ones therefore avoiding errors on client side.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I'd like to point out an alternative and less expensive way to accomplish what I asked on this question.

[Hoa/Mime](https://github.com/hoaproject/Mime) is a library that does just what I asked. It had not been releasead at the time of the question.

`print_r(Hoa\Mime\Mime::getExtensionsFromMime('text/html'));` will print

```
Array
(
    [0] => html
    [1] => htm
)
```

Similarly, `var_dump(Hoa\Mime\Mime::getMimeFromExtension('webm'));` will print `string(10) "video/webm"`.

A `Mime` object also has the methods `getExtension()` and `getOtherExtensions()`, so I can check for alternative acceptable content-types, without coming up with my own lookup table.

This is a little more complete than @Issam Zoli's answer, as it provides room for returning, for example, `text/xml` when an `application/xml` is requested. His answer is great for a lower-level understanding of what must be done, if one wishes to implement on his own, instead of using a third-party bundle.